Now that there's pattern matching in Dart is it best to use it for iterating over maps?
Traditionally, to iterate over the keys and values of a Map you can write this:
  map.forEach((key, value) {

  });

But with the introduction of patterns in Dart 3.0 you could actually write it as
  for (var MapEntry(:key, :value) in map.entries) {

  }

In fact, such a construction is given as example at the patterns documentation in the For and for-in loops section.
I suppose whether it's a better code style is subjective, but is one way better than the other in terms of performance/memory?

Note that Iterable.forEach is generally faster than for-in loops (at least in some cases).  The better performance of Map.forEach maybe is related.  Also, I wouldn't personally depend on one being more performant than the other; that's something that could change.

The performance can be estimated with a benchmark:
import 'package:benchmark_runner/benchmark_runner.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  final mapSize = 100000;
  final list = List<int>.generate(mapSize, (index) => index);
  final map = {for (var element in list) element: element.toString()};
  final result = <int, String>{};

  benchmark('Iterating using forEach: map size $mapSize', () {
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      result[key] = '$value-new';
    });
  });
  result.clear();
  benchmark('Iterating over map keys: map size $mapSize', () {
    for (final key in map.keys) {
      result[key] = '${map[key]!}-new';
    }
  });
  result.clear();
  benchmark('Pattern for loop: map size $mapSize', () {
    for (final MapEntry(:key, :value) in map.entries) {
      result[key] = '$value-new';
    }
  });
}

Benchmark scores for map size 100:
[244ms:881us] Iterating using forEach: map size 100
    mean: 7.24 ± 1.030 us, median: 7.032 ± 0.66 us
    ▆▉▂▂____________ sample size: 40 (averaged over 131 runs)
  
[242ms:617us] Iterating over map keys: map size 100
    mean: 7.50 ± 0.42 us, median: 7.51 ± 0.49 us
    ▆▄▉▁___ sample size: 41 (averaged over 124 runs)
  
[236ms:322us] Pattern for loop: map size 100
    mean: 9.12 ± 0.48 us, median: 9.11 ± 0.69 us
    ▇▉▄▁_ sample size: 30 (averaged over 115 runs)

Benchmark scores for map size 100000:
[811ms:165us] Iterating using forEach: map size 100000
    mean: 10.47 ± 1.97 ms, median: 9.60 ± 1.66 ms
    ▉▁▃________ sample size: 49
  
[890ms:338us] Iterating over map keys: map size 100000
    mean: 12.18 ± 2.013 ms, median: 11.20 ± 2.31 ms
    ▉▁▅______ sample size: 48
  
[01s:004ms] Pattern for loop: map size 100000
    mean: 14.47 ± 2.63 ms, median: 13.97 ± 2.51 ms
    ▉▃▇_________ sample size: 47

Benchmark scores for map size 1000000:
[04s:144ms] Iterating using forEach: map size 1000000
    mean: 217.80 ± 12.30 ms, median: 214.88 ± 18.029 ms
    ▉▇▂▄ sample size: 10
  
[06s:004ms] Iterating over map keys: map size 1000000
    mean: 353.59 ± 28.75 ms, median: 358.84 ± 57.83 ms
    ▇▄▂▉ sample size: 10
  
[06s:947ms] Pattern for loop: map size 1000000
    mean: 413.17 ± 10.85 ms, median: 413.095 ± 16.46 ms
    ▄▉▄▄ sample size: 10

Conclusion: The benchmark scores show a slighly better performance when using forEach to iterate over maps. However, for moderate map sizes, the performance gain is too small to recommend one style over another.
Note: The benchmarks were performed on a i5-6260U CPU @ 1.80GHz with 32GB RAM.

Performance is hard to generalize. The performance of iterating a map can depend on the underlying implementation, which may depend on the type of key. (When compiled to JavaScript, integer and string keys may be special-cased because JavaScript treats them differently as object keys.)
The for (var MapEntry(:key, :value) in map.entries) {...} should be comparable to for (var entry in mapEntries) { var key = entry.key, value = entry.value; ...}.
Using forEach is usually much faster because it lets the map itself drive the iteration, instead of providing an Iterable that the for-in iterates through. Even more efficient than iterating .entries, if that needs to allocate a MapEntry per step. The forEach doesn't have to be able to stop after each element, or create an object to hold key and value, it can keep its entire iteration state on the stack.
On the other hand forEach does require an function call to a user-provided function for each entry. That can be harder to optimize than the iteration loop, especially if the call point doesn't know which implementation of Map it's calling forEach on. If the optimizing compiler knows it's optimizing a platform map iteration, maybe it can do better.
Performance will depend more on which optimizations can be applied to the code, than which choice of iteration is chosen. Which optimizations can be applied may currently depend on the choice of iteration, but optimizations can change at any moment. Usually for the better.
The benchmarks of Dan R are most likely dominated by the operations inside the loops. Adding a new entry to a map is likely as expensive as creating a MapEntry. A more direct benchmark could be something like:

class Key {
  final int id;
  Key(this.id);
  int get hashCode => id ^ 37;
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is Key && id == other.id;
}

void main() {
  for (var mapSize = 1000; mapSize <= 100000; mapSize *= 10) {
    test<int>((x) => x, mapSize);
    test<String>((x) => "$x", mapSize);
    test<Key>(Key.new, mapSize);
  }
}

void test<K>(K Function(int) makeKey, int mapSize) {
  final map = <K, int>{for (var i = 0; i < mapSize; i++) makeKey(i): i};
  int expectedResult = mapSize ~/ 2 * (mapSize - 1);
  K lastKey = makeKey(-1);
  int result = 0;
  benchmark('Map<$K, int>.forEach #$mapSize', mapSize, () {
    result = 0;
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      lastKey = key;
      result += value;
    });
  });
  if (lastKey != makeKey(mapSize - 1)) throw "Bad key: $lastKey";
  if (result != expectedResult) throw "Bad result: $result, expected: $expectedResult";

  lastKey = makeKey(-1);
  benchmark('for-in Map<$K, int>.keys+[] #$mapSize', mapSize, () {
    result = 0;
    for (final key in map.keys) {
      lastKey = key;
      result += map[key]!;
    }
  });
  if (lastKey != makeKey(mapSize - 1)) throw "Bad key: $lastKey";
  if (result != expectedResult) throw "Bad result: $result, expected: $expectedResult";

  lastKey = makeKey(-1);
  benchmark('for-in Map<$K, int>.entries #$mapSize', mapSize, () {
    result = 0;
    for (final entry in map.entries) {
      lastKey = entry.key;
      result += entry.value;
    }
  });
  if (lastKey != makeKey(mapSize - 1)) throw "Bad key: $lastKey";
  if (result != expectedResult) throw "Bad result: $result, expected: $expectedResult";

  lastKey = makeKey(-1);
  benchmark('Pattern for loop: map size $mapSize', mapSize, () {
    result = 0;
    for (final MapEntry(:key, :value) in map.entries) {
      lastKey = key;
      result += value;
    }
  });
  if (lastKey != makeKey(mapSize - 1)) throw "Bad key: $lastKey";
  if (result != expectedResult) throw "Bad result: $result, expected: $expectedResult";

  print("");
}

void benchmark(String name, int problemSize, void Function() operation,
               [int limitMS = 1500]) {
  var c = 0, e = 0, n = 100;
  var sw = Stopwatch()..start();
  do {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      operation();
    }
    e = sw.elapsedMilliseconds;
    c += problemSize * n;
    n *= 2;
  } while (e < limitMS);
  if (limitMS >= 200) {
    print("$name: ${(c/e).toStringAsFixed(3)} /ms");
  }
}

When compiled with dart compile exe, it shows forEach being ~7-10 times faster than iterating entries, with or without patterns, ~4 times faster than iterating keys and doing an extra lookup. Slower for string keys than int or the custom Key, likely because String.hashCode and String.== are slower to begin with (they have to check all characters).

Map<int, int>.forEach #10000: 250000.000 /ms
for-in Map<int, int>.keys+[] #10000: 69741.900 /ms
for-in Map<int, int>.entries #10000: 42631.756 /ms
Pattern for loop: map size 10000: 42732.167 /ms

Map<String, int>.forEach #10000: 234188.818 /ms
for-in Map<String, int>.keys+[] #10000: 50637.959 /ms
for-in Map<String, int>.entries #10000: 33707.865 /ms
Pattern for loop: map size 10000: 33528.473 /ms

Map<Key, int>.forEach #10000: 231956.423 /ms
for-in Map<Key, int>.keys+[] #10000: 64076.690 /ms
for-in Map<Key, int>.entries #10000: 42617.450 /ms
Pattern for loop: map size 10000: 42150.680 /ms

That won't mean that your code will be 10 times faster if you use forEach, unless you do nothing of significance in the loop body.
I'd write the code for readability, where I prefer the pattern approach, and only consider changing that if I have measured that map iteration is the bottle-neck.
